# Update post meta on wordpress and woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy creando un e-commerce basado en turismo donde en la pagina de pago se muestra el viaje comprado junto a la cantidad de personas que van a viajar. Esta cantidad se puede cambiar en la misma página y entonces tras el cambio se renderizan los datos del viajero tantas veces como viajeros van a comprar. Los datos son los siguientes :

- Nombre.
- Documento identificativo.
- Email

Esto ya lo tengo desarrollado en PHP y javascript pero el problema esta en que cuando se cambia la cantidad y se renderizan los campos, estos no se incluyen en la llamada post al finalizar la compra.

En PHP creo un array tal que asi:

```
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
'traveller_details' => array(
    'type' => 'traveller_details',
    'required'      => false,
    'label' => __( 'Traveller details' )
    ),
);
```

Despues, actualizo mediante una accion el post meta :

```
function supreme_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ){

  if( ! empty( $posted["traveller_details"] ) ){
    update_post_meta( $order_id, "_traveller_details", $posted["traveller_details"] );
  } else {
    delete_post_meta( $order_id, "_traveller_details" );
  }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'supreme_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Mi pregunta es como podría capturar los valores antes de enviar el post y enviarlos en la llamada post.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés. Por favor edita tu pregunta y traduce a español.

Comment: ... Y luego de traducirla, deberías especificar con más detalle qué datos se deberían guardar en el meta del post y qué intentaste hasta ahora. Quizás te ayuda leer [ask]

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de traductir. Perdonad, pensaba que estaba en la versión inglesa de stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Mi pregunta es como podría capturar los valores antes de enviar el post y enviarlos en la llamada post.

Sólo agrega la clave `'default'` al array y como valor le colocas el resultado del `get_post_meta()`:

```
$datos = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_traveller_details' , true );

$fields['extra_fields'] = array(
        'traveller_details' => array(
        'type'              => 'traveller_details',
        'required'          => false,
        'label'             => __( 'Traveller details' )
        'default'           => $datos // si el resultado es un string. Si es array sería $datos['algo']
    ),
);
```

Con eso el campo vendrá con los valores.

Otra cosa: dices que...

> En PHP creo un array tal que asi:

Asumo que escribiste ese array así "pelado" para resumir, pero si no es así debes colocarlo dentro en una función y asignarle un filtro.